# MySQL: how to convert SQL file to Workbench mwb file

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I have a sql file that creates a database with all tables. But I want to work on the database in MySQL Workbench which provide UI interface. So I think I need to create a MySQL Model from the database that created by the SQL file. Didn't find a way to do it. There must be a way. Searched but all are from mwb to sql. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You can create database structure with any tool that you know. After that, connect to it with MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Home Screen on MySQL Workbench, click the arrow seen below that I circled in Red and create the model either based on an existing db or a script. It will bring up the Reverse Engineer screen. Proceed accordingly.

[image]

The above is from Workbench 6.3.3

Comment: I know it was a lame answer but how far could I take it :p

Answer (score 6):

If you already have created your model, you will need to do a reverse engineer, with this you can see the model and then go to file - save model, this will save your model as mwb

### Step 1

[image]

### Step 2 ( Next , next, select your database and click execute)

[image]

### Step 3 (In your EER view go to File - save model as)

[image]